# How to convert an array into a string with spaces every index in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

So I have an array:
`var arr = ['foo,', 'bar', 'red,', 'car'];`

How can I convert it into a string, but with spaces every index, like this?

`'foo, bar red, car'`

I could use `arr.join()`, but then I would have a bunch of unwanted commas.

Comment: is that a typo in you array or are commas intentional?

Comment: You want commas in the resulting string?

Comment: The commas in the strings are intentional, but I don't want the ones that aren't in the strings. (The array separators, or whatever their called)

Comment: @HyperEdge Don't know why you got downvotes, seemed like a good question to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
var arr = ['foo,', 'bar', 'red,', 'car'];

console.log(arr.join(' '));
```

Comment: @HyperEdge If it is resolved then check answered please.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to but it said I could only do it in 10 minutes, by which time I was gone. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the delimiter you want in the call to `join()`. You only get commas if you use the default delimiter.

```js
var arr = ['foo,', 'bar', 'red,', 'car'];
var result = arr.join(' ');
console.log(result);
```